# Is the French word tempérance used to describe the virtue of temperance?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Temperance is often considered a virtue in Christian and classical philosophy. You find this concept in Plato as the word σωφροσύνη.

Would the French word tempérance be used to describe this virtue? I suspect so, but I wanted to make sure. It's the obvious cognate to the English word, but you never know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the word "tempérance" is used to describe this virtue, a core virtue in Christianity.

[Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/temp%C3%A9rance/77209) -   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperance_(virtue))